# Why does jQuery not register my <a> click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the example below

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">test</a>
<button id="btn-add">Add</button>
<div id="placeholder">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('a').on('click', function () {
            alert('clicked');
        });

        $("#btn-add").on("click", function () {
            $('#placeholder').prepend('<a href=\'#\'>blah2</a>');
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you click on 'Add' then 'blah2' nothing happens even though I am trying to alert on any anchor click.  As a check if you click on 'test'you get the popup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('body').on("click", "a", function () {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/f7E8C/)

Answer (score 3):

Since the element is generated dynamically, you need to use delegation with the `on()` method or create a literal jQuery object and add a click event.

```
$('closestParent').on('click', 'a', function(){ ... })

// OR

var $link = $('<a href=\'#\'>blah2</a>').click(function(){ ... })
$link.prependTo('#placeholder')
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you need to delegate the click to a parent element.  If you are using 1.7+ use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or if you are using 1.6 and lower you can use .delegate().  The element doesn't exist when the dom is ready so you need to [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) the event to a parent element.  Meaning you can use `$(document)` or use any parent element that is already there

```
$(document).on("click","a", function () {  //<-- this allows for the event to bubble up to the document in this case
        alert('clicked');
});

$(document).delegate("a","click", function () {
        alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't delegate an event to the `$(document)` - you'd want to use the closest parent.